# puTTy registry changing certain presets

Tags: shell, ssh, registry, putty

I am fixing presets through the `.reg` file instead of in puTTy because I am going to make this an open source registry. Mostly changing themes, and my school doesn't know what the hell they are doing and most of us would rather have the right click (context menu) option available to us. Here is a quick example of what I am editing::

```
"AlwaysOnTop"=dword:00000000
"FullScreenOnAltEnter"=dword:00000001
"HideMousePtr"=dword:00000001
"SunkenEdge"=dword:00000001
"WindowBorder"=dword:00000001
"CurType"=dword:00000000
"BlinkCur"=dword:00000001
```

Which I am guessing `dword` accepts binary. Can someone tell me where in these options is the right click override? Or if there is documentation for dummys basically of what each of these properties mean give me the link so I can read it?

Comment: Why you trying to close this? It's a simple question, if it's not possible simply state that. I'll accept that as an answer, though all these other options are available so this one must be as well. All I need is the property name.

Comment: Stack Overflow is for programming-related questions. This question might be more relevant on something like http://superuser.com/

Comment: Oh ok, thought it was more of the sort of a "programming language" since registries are a document that accepts binary

Comment: I'm confused about what you are trying to change and I'm confused as to why you are trying to directly edit this in the registry instead of using the putt configuration UI.

Comment: Because we are in Server Side Scripting class and our Professor seems to think puTTy is easier than FTP. So I am creating themes for users, and for my class mates the contextmenu is better and some don't understand how to do it so I figured to set it in the reg and not the UI (since I can't programmatically)

Comment: There's an answer at http://superuser.com/q/819046/4714